# What does "Compatibility libraries (toolchain)" mean in CentOS Wiki

Tags: centos, toolchain

I'm reading [this page](https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product#fnref-a91b3c0c287c782f9af063daff9e64b566d648c7), there's a line about `Compatibility libraries (toolchain)`:

[image]

Does it mean programs compiled on CentOS 6 will be able to run on CentOS 5?

In my experience it usually won't work due to glibc version issue. So what does this line mean?

Answer (score 0):

Comparability libraries let you run something compiled for CentOS 6 on CentOS 7, not the other direction.  It is to help you migrate to a newer version.